# Must statement in yang

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

my CLI looks like -

```
router config
site site123
   eid-prefix instance-id 100 1.1.1.0/24 accept-more-specifics 
   eid-prefix instance-id 102 2.2.2.0/24 accept-more-specifics 
   eid-prefix instance-id 103 3.3.3.0/24 accept-more-specifics 
site site345
   eid-prefix instance-id 104 4.4.1.0/24 accept-more-specifics 
   eid-prefix instance-id 106 6.6.2.0/24 accept-more-specifics 
extranet ext1
   eid-record-provider instance-id 103
```

I need a must statement for CLI "eid-record-provider" which validates if the instance-id being used there is defined under "site".

I have written something like -

```
 tailf:cli-diff-dependency "../../../../site/eid-prefix/instance-id/id";
 must "../../../../site[name = current()]/eid-prefix/instance-id[id = current() ]" {
   error-message "% Please configure site before provider instance";   
 }
```

I am not sure how i am going to iterate must for all sites, as "site" is a list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate on all leaves; you may constrain the `must` at the level of `eid-prefix`: if it is a `leaf`, read [Section 7.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.6.2).